# Can I invalidate an arbitrary cache entry with Varnish?

Tags: rest, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am investigating if I can use Varnish to speed up a REST API.

Basically, I want to cache the `GET` requests for a potentially long time. But when a `PUT`/`POST`/`DELETE` request is received, I want to parse the URL and, based on the information I find, I want to purge a cache entry.

For example:

```
GET /documents/:docType // return document list for specified docType
DELETE /document/:docType/:docId // delete a document

GET /documents/A0  <-- cached
GET /documents/A1  <-- cached
DELETE /document/A0/333  <-- first entry is purged
```

Can I achieve this with VCL?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this [varnish tutorial entry](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html) where purge and ban are explained.

You should be careful when purging as you shouldn't allow everyone to purge an url.

In order to do that you should do something like:

```
# IPs allowed to purge
acl purgeIps {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}
```

Then in your vcl_recv you have to decide when to purge/ban:

```
if (req.request == "PUT" ||
    req.request == "POST" ||
    req.request == "DELETE"){
    if (!client.ip ~ purgeIps) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
    purge; #I'm not sure if purge can be done here, if it doesn't work you should use it in vcl_hit and vcl_miss
    # Also, if purge does not work here you should change this line for return(lookup);
    error 200 "Purged";
}
```

[Here](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Cache_invalidation.html) you can find more examples about banning and purging

Comment: You cannot do much harm enabling PURGE, as it evicts a single object, matched by the exact URL, and the URL cannot contain wildcards (as Varnish stores objects with a hash identifier and not by the URL itself so patterns are meaningless). On the other hand, BAN might be dangerous,

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Nevertheless, thinking about it deeper and without being 100% sure, maybe if you allow purge to a heavy static object you get exposed to a DDoS attack by purging and loading repeatedly.

Comment: Whatever method you use, if you enable - say - the PUT method in a request, which is followed by a newly generated response, you will still be vulnerable to DDoS as this process cannot be cached. A potential attacker only needs to find the appropriate URL for that PUT. Although without knowing the internals of the application, it is not trivial to know what those heavy objects are.